# VBA Vlookup "application-defined or object-defined" error in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, office365, vlookup

I tried to use the excel VBA vlookup, but I get this error "application-defined or object-defined" for line number 4.

```
Dim SearchRange As Range
Dim FindRow As Range
Set SearchRange = Sheet2.Range("A4", Sheet2.Range("A65536").End(xlUp))

Set FindRow = SearchRange.Find("Car 4", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

Comment: Actually using `Find` is not `VLOOKUP`! Checkout the [WorksheetFunction.VLookup method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.vlookup).

Comment: Is this your exact code?  It doesn't have any obvious problems which would cause the error you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Check your serach range `SearchRange`. Eg by either using one of these statements:

- `Debug.Print SearchRange.Address`
- `MsgBox SearchRange.Address`

Further improvements:

1. Never hardcode `A65536` as last cell. Always use it like

   ```
   Sheet2.Range("A4", Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
   ```

   because `Rows.Count` gives you the true amount of rows (newer Excel versions have more than `65536` rows).
2. Note that the documentation of the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) says:

   > *The settings for `LookIn`, `LookAt`, `SearchOrder`, and `MatchByte` are saved each time you use this method.*

   So if you don't define all of the 4 mentioned parameters VBA will use whatever was used last, either by VBA or the user interface. Since the user inteface is out of your control you will get random results if you don't define them **all**.

   ```
   Set FindRow = SearchRange.Find(What:="Car 4", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchByte:=False)
   ```
3. Make sure to check if something was found before using `FindRow`

   ```
   Dim SearchRange As Range
   Set SearchRange = Sheet2.Range("A4", Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

   Dim FindRow As Range
   Set FindRow = SearchRange.Find(What:="Car 4", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchByte:=False)

   'check if something was found
   If Not FindRow Is Nothing Then
       'successful
       MsgBox "found in row " & FindRow.Row
   Else
       MsgBox "'Car 4' was not found in range " & SearchRange.Address
   End If
   ```